# Simple - LinqToTwitter objects & properties

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-twitter

I am attempting to use LinqToTwitter for the first time and I have a question about it's objects & properties.

If anyone has a link to a list of objects & their properties, that would work perfectly.

For now, I am trying to use [THIS](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ffbabcf9f7d3#ReadMe.txt) as a guide. It's the closest I've found. I'm looking under the "LinkToTwitterAG" section. Not sure what the AG stands for, but this gives a list of objects.

My ultimate goal is to display a user's Username & a list of their Status's in a ListView. My current code for the databound list items is

' />
' />

The text within the Eval(" ") represents the 'Object.Property' I wish to display. It defaults to the 'LinqToTwitter' namespace. So, going by the code I linked to above, LinqToTwitter.Contributor.ScreenName should be valid, but I get an error during debug saying that LinqToTwitter.Contributor is invalid.

Comment: Please re-edit that question, as your code is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to Twitter has a [Making API Calls Documentation](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Making%20API%20Calls) page with all the available command and queries and their associated parameters. Each API also has a link to the entity type it returns. Another feature of the API documentation is a link to the corresponding Twitter API documentation at the bottom of each page. You can also inspect the [LINQ to Twitter Entities](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20Entities) page to learn about these objects and their properties.

In addition to [General Documentation](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/documentation), the [downloadable source code](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ffbabcf9f7d3#ReadMe.txt) includes samples for each API call, with numerous examples of how to use various parameters. There's also a [Samples](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20Samples) page where you'll find even more demos broken into the various technologies that LINQ to Twitter supports.